# Flight information data

Tags: data-acquisition

I would like to write a program that automatically checks whether a given flight number is correct and the corresponding departure and arrival times.

Is there any function from the Wolfram Language that grants access to such data?

Comment: I don't believe there's a built-in function for this. You may want to look into the [OpenSky Network API](https://opensky-network.org/apidoc/).

Comment: @CarlLange Well WolframAlpha knows about flights, so that can be utilized in Mathematica. See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=delta+flight+354 . Or try `WolframAlpha["delta flight 354"]` in Mathematica.

Comment: @AntonAntonov Ah yes, indeed. Also usable from WL as `WolframAlphaResult["delta flight 354", {{"FlightSchedule:FlightData", 1}, "Content"}]`. However it doesn't look like this information is built into the standard language but is a WolframAlpha only feature :(

Comment: @CarlLange even though this is not a Mathematica-related subject anymore, I can't resist to ask. Does such API work for future flights, scheduled in, let's say 3 months? Because as far as I could see, it only provides information on aircrafts which are currently in the airspace...

Comment: @AntonAntonov Is it possible that such query only works for American flights? I didn't retrieve any information for some random European flight number.

Comment: @Mat I'm afraid I have no idea. There are a few other APIs available, but I didn't look into it in detail. My guess would be that WA integration is for FAA flights only, rather than worldwide - the only European airline flights I can get are ones that start or end in the US.